# Connecting to apache server on local network?

Tags: apache

So I wanted to connect to my apache server on my local network via a router which I have connected two computers to via ethernet cables.

My host computer can easily access localhost/phpmyadmin but the other computer can't access to that webpage. Now I have added a user on the mysql server with granted access to do everything and it has allowed it from any host, that would say the ip can be %.%.%.%!

In the apache httpd.conf I have added the line Listen *:80
In the httpd-xampp.conf I have edited the code to this.

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Is there anyway I can fix this? I went to the router webpage and removed the SPI firewall, I rebooted the router so that the webmanagent port is using port 81 instead of 80.

Please any help?

Comment: Can you access any pages on the server?  Can you ping the server from the client to ensure routing/connectivity?

Comment: I can access every page via the host computer, but nothing via the client.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem! The problem was that I used the wrong adress to connect, and I don't have admin access on these computers so I couldn't easily check the ip adress of the host computer and I guessed, but I contacted admin and he gave the correct adress so I could connect to the site.